# f:ajax method gets called on load of the jsf page

Tags: jsf-2

I've simple 3line jsf page and a backing bean. I'm using command button in my page. Onclick event I'm calling ajax.  where ajax method adds an output text component to child. Now the problem is. Out put text component is rendered on load of the page rather than on click of the page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton id="button1" action="return false" value="Submit">
                <f:ajax execute="#{bb.method1()}" render="@form" transient="true" event="click" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Backing bean code

```
@Named("bb")
@SessionScoped
public class BackingBean implements Serializable {

public BackingBean() {
}

public void method1()
{
    HtmlOutputText out=new HtmlOutputText();
    out.setValue("Text1");
    FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getViewRoot().getChildren().add(out);
    context.getViewRoot().setTransient(true);
}   
}
```

on click of button firebug show status 200 OK.. But I can see no changes at the page

Comment: In your f:ajax you should use listener instead of execute! Check this link to view examples of ajax : http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/ . And I have no idea of what is doing transcient attribute. You can remove your action also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `execute` attribute should refer a space separated collection of client IDs of input components which needs to be processed during ajax submit. This attribute is evaluated when the view get rendered and any method bound to it thus get invoked immediately.

You should be using the `listener` attribute instead.

```
<f:ajax listener="#{bb.method1()}" render="@form" transient="true" event="click" />
```

The same is true for the `render` attribute.

#### See also:

- [`<f:ajax>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html)

Comment: Followed what you had mentioned I'm unable  to add New Html tag on Ajax call. FireBug Shows Successful response. But It has update update tag rather than insert xml tag

Comment: That's a different problem. You're adding the new component as child of viewroot, but you're only updating the form. You need to add it as child of form instead, or to update the entire viewroot. By the way, this approach is smelly. Look at `rendered` attribute or using faces messages.

Comment: Yeah thanks  BalusC, After roaming around a4j, primefaces. found using simple jquery post method and servlet was much easier, for adding html element in jsf..............